# WinRT WebView Control

Tags: html, webview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, opacity

I have the following control in a Windows Metro App:

```
string html = "<html><body>test content</body></head>";
myWebView.Opacity = 0.5;
myWebView.NavigateToString(html);
```

This works okay, but what I end up with is a blank white background with black text.  What I actually want is for this to work with the current Metro style (so match the dark or light background depending on the setting).  I've played with the `Opacity` setting, as above, but it seems to make no difference.

Is there a way to get the WebView control to mirror the current Metro style?

Comment: You could do the application in HTML and get it for free or otherwise - I think you would need to replicate it manually with your own CSS.

Comment: Any updates on this? Running in to the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is by design.** `WebView`-Controls don't support any `Opacity`, cause they are kind of a special control which is rendered on top of everything.

[From the MSDN docs:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx)

> WebView has the characteristic that other UI regions such as controls cannot be rendered on top of the WebView. This is because of how window regions are handled internally, particularly how input events are processed and how the screen draws. If you want to render HTML content and also place other UI elements on top of that HTML content, you should use WebViewBrush as the render area. The WebView still provides the HTML source information, and you reference that WebView through element name binding and the SourceName property. WebViewBrush does not have this overlay limitation.